# Values of variables don't update properly for new loop in pygame

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame, mouse

Using pygame and python 3.7, I have created a game in which an image at the center (250, 250) can be dragged around the screen and collide with a radius, in which case a break happens and the next image in the next loop spawns at the exact center, where the first image was located, as well. Despite the game working the way I intended, in principle, it behaves weirdly for fast mouse speed. In my minimal example code, the colored circles are supposed to reappear at the exact center, for every while-loop, however, they somehow don't update properly and therefore reappear not at the center of the screen, most of the time (they only do when I release the mouse-button really early / well-timed). I tested the game on windows and mac and noticed that on my mac, the "lag" seems to be even worse. If anybody knows how I could work around that, I'd be really thankful. Also, the game starts lagging and jumping to the next loop right away for really fast mouse movement, with which I have dealt by changing the speed of my external mouse. Is there an inherent fix for too fast mouse-movement in pygame? Thanks for all suggestions and maybe also other improvements to the idea of my code.

```
import pygame
import time
from time import sleep
import math

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_surface = pygame.Surface((500, 500))

background_surface.fill((255, 255, 255))

colors = [(0,0,0), (253, 45, 0), (249, 253, 0), (32, 201, 5), (0, 210, 235)]

for color in colors:

    done = False

    a, b = 250, 250

    u, v = 250, 250

    while not done:

        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if event.buttons[0]:
                    a += event.rel[0]
                    b += event.rel[1]


        rect = pygame.Rect(u, v, 0.001, 0.001)
        radius = 200
        corners = [rect.bottomleft, rect.bottomright, rect.topleft, rect.topright]
        dist = [math.sqrt((p[0] - a) ** 2 + (p[1] - b) ** 2) for p in corners]
        p_out = [i for i, d in enumerate(dist) if d > radius]

        if any(p_out):
            break

        gameDisplay.blit(background_surface, (0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color, (a,b), 50, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, (0,0,0), (250,250), 200, 2)
        pygame.display.flip()
    sleep(0.7)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...]  they somehow don't update properly and therefore reappear not at the center of the screen, most of the time (they only do when I release the mouse-button really early / well-timed) [...]

Of course, investigate your code. The 1st thing what happens in your code is, that `a` and `b` are modified:

> ```
> while not done:
>    # [...]
>
> for event in pygame.event.get():
>    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>         done = True
>     elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
>         if event.buttons[0]:
>             a += event.rel[0]
>             b += event.rel[1]
> ```

If the `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event is in the queue, then it is handled before the circle is drawn. So the position of the circle is modified and it does not appear in the center.
Note, an event does not reflect the current state of the mouse. It is a notification, which is stored in a queue when it happens, but then event handling may done later. What you actually do is to handle an event, which possibly occurred in the past.

Use a state `dragging`, which is `False` at the start of each loop. Set the state when the button is pressed (`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event) and reset it when the button is released (`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` event):

```py
for color in colors:

    # [...]

    dragging = False
    while not done:

        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    dragging = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:
                    dragging = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if dragging:
                    a += event.rel[0]
                    b += event.rel[1]

        # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, again! Also, great explanation.